# Find match in a range in word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

is there any way to find a next match in a specified range if there are 2 matches in the range. or if there is any way to get a list of all the matches.
currently I am using the below interop method to find the match but it will highlight only the first match.

```
bool found = foundRange.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See inline comments:

```
 //Get any range you want
var range = app.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges[WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory];


var document = range.Document;

//We want the variable range to continue refering to the same Range at all times
var foundRange = range.Duplicate;

if (foundRange.Find.Execute("j", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, WdFindWrap.wdFindStop, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found first");
    //After using .Execute(), FoundRange has been set to the found text
    Console.WriteLine(foundRange.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't find first");
}

//Set foundRange to start at the character after the last find and to end where the original range ends
foundRange = document.Range(foundRange.Start + 1, range.End);

//Repeat. Obviously you could use some kind of loop
if (foundRange.Find.Execute("j", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, WdFindWrap.wdFindStop, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found second");
    Console.WriteLine(foundRange.Text);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didn't find second");
}

foundRange.Select(); //Just to verify. We don't need the selection object for anything
```